# weird behavior of list.append( ) function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I am really confused by `list.append()` in my code below, could you anyone let me know what I have misunderstood and got wrong.

```
nums=[3,1,2,4]
path = []
res =[]
while nums:
    path += [nums.pop(0)]
    print("path = ", path)
    res.append(path)
    print("res=", res)

output:
path =  [3]
res= [[3]]
path =  [3, 1]
res= [[3, 1], [3, 1]]
path =  [3, 1, 2]
res= [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
path =  [3, 1, 2, 4]
res= [[3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4]]
```

I expect `res` to be `[[3],[3,1],[3,1,2],[3,1,2,4]]`. I just don't understand the behavior of `append()` in the code above.

when I change `path += [nums.pop(0)]` to `path = path + [nums.pop(0)]` , then everything seems to work fine. What I have missed here?

Comment: There is *only one single* ``path`` object that gets repeatedly extended via ``nums.pop`` and appended to ``res``. Use ``path = path + [nums.pop(0)]`` to create a new ``path`` object for each iteration step.

Comment: Change the append to `res.append(path[:])` to get desired result.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, thank you very very much for your help. The link answers my question very well. Have a wonderful day.